# Javascript function call error: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: javascript

I wanted to access my array variable in javascript by passing it as a parameter to a javascript onlick function call. But it returns an error mention in the title above. Here is my code:

**Php file**

```
<?php $pastDueArr = []; ?>

@foreach ($pastDueReports as $key => $val)

              <?php

                  $date1 = date_create();
                  $date2 = date_create($val->schedule);
                  $diff  = date_diff($date1,$date2);

                  $pastDueArr[$key]['id'] = $val->id;
                  $pastDueArr[$key]['past_due'] = (int)$diff->format("%a");
              ?>

 @endforeach

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="pastDues( {{ 
 $pastDueArr }} )"></i> Update Past Dues</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function pastDues(pastDues){

        console.log(pastDues);

          }
```

Error:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because in `{{ $pastDueArr }}` you have an array where a string is expected.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="pastDues( {{ 
 $pastDueArr }} )"></i> Update Past Dues</button>
```

Comment: @Eli It is not clear what you are trying to do. You will need use some method of serializing your datastructure between your frontend and backend if you want to pass that data between them.

Comment: I just wanted to pass/access that php array variable to javascript. Thats all. When I pass the $pastDueReports instead of $pastDueArr, it is working but not with the $pastDueArr.

Comment: The most common means of serializing data is JSON, but there are many ways to do it. You could even construct the javascript data structure in your PHP template.